# Just want to know how the code is actually running

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i;
void inc(int i)
{
  i++;
}

int main()
{
  for(int i=0;i<10;inc(i))
  {
    cout<<i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is infinite zeroes..
How does it give that

Comment: Presumably, you'd be expecting the output to be 0123456789?

Comment: yes! but the output is not that

Comment: You have three ***different*** variables named `i`.

Comment: This does not look like C++/CLI code, but standard C++ *command line* program. Big difference!

Comment: Trace it in a debugger. And fix your indentation.

Comment: Changed tag from c++-cli to c++ to reflect actual language used.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `i` (declared in the loop) by value in `inc`, so `i` is not actually being incremented. You need to pass `i` by reference.

To do this, change

```
void inc(int i) { 
   i++; 
}
```

to:

```
void inc(int& i) { 
   i++; 
}
```

This will pass the address of `i` (reference) to `inc`, which will increment the value stored at that address.

Here is your final code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i;//no use of this variale
void inc(int& i) { 
   i++; 
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;inc(i))
    {
        cout<<i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do i do that then?

Comment: @PhilGabardo write it inside your answer.It is a valid answer

Comment: If this is C++, why not a reference? Also `void inc(*int i)` is not correct.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error, my C++ is rusty, its fixed now. Not sure what you mean by: "If this is C++, why not a reference?".

Comment: The idiomatic way to pass something by reference in C++ is to use a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks. Is this the same for C?

Comment: No, C does not have references.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I've updated my solution to use references instead of pointers.

Comment: But it still says "This will pass the address of i (pointer) to inc, which will increment the value stored at that address." Just changing "pointer" to "reference" doesn't make that sentence accurate, a reference is not an address (even if that's how  the compiler implements it internally)

Comment: What would you consider `i` to be then, in `inc(i)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simple way like this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      cout<<i;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's rename some of your variables:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int i1;

void inc(int i2)
{
  i2++;
}

int main()
{
  for(int i3=0;i3<10;inc(i3))
  {
    cout<<i3;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Does that make it clear what's happening?

Nothing ever uses `i1`, it's completely pointless.

You increment `i2` but that's a local variable, completely separate from `i3`. Each time the loop runs you call `inc(i3)` which creates a new local variable called `i2` and copies the value of `i3` (which is always zero), increments the local variable then that variable goes out of scope and its lifetime ends. So your `inc` function has no side-effects and `i3` is never changed.

Your function should be `inc(int& i)` so that it takes its argument by reference and can modify it.